# Understanding SQL Join in this statement

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

Now I have the following Query

```
select  *
from
      Actors
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      ActorRoles on   Actors.ActorID = ActorRoles .ActorID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Movies on   ActorRoles.MovieID= Movies.MovieID
```

So I get the following columns - the brackets indicate the column no

```
ActorID(1) Name(2) ActorID(3) MovieID(4) Role(5) MovieID(6) Title(7) Genre(8)
```

I am confused as to how these columns are showing up. There is already an ActorID column then why is another ActorID column showing up ? How do I know which table does this ActorID Column belong to ?

Comment: You shouldn't 'select *'. Specify the columns you want and from what tables. You should also look into SQL Aliases for tables and columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are "Select *", every column from every table will show up.  Since ActorID is in 2 tables, it shows up twice in your column list.

Answer (score 2):

You did select * which means all columns from all tables in the join will show up.  It doesn't care that they have the same name, you'll get teh ActorId column from your Actors table as well as from your ActorRoles table.